# Unsupported Type Exception in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Wondering what is the most appropiate `Exception` to throw
when there is some case where I get an implementation of an interface
that I don't expect

Is there such a thing as `UnsupportedTypeException` in .Net that I'm not aware of?
Cheers

Comment: In what situation would you be getting an implementation of an interface that is not allowed? The interface is used because you want to be able to switch in and out types without caring.

Comment: Liskov substitution principle!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NotSupportedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx) exists that may be what you want to consider.

Comment: This is not the intended way of using this exception, see the very first line in the MSDN article about this exception.

Answer (score 3):

What is not supported? When its not supported, why does your function takes it as parameter? 
This is not good design, because the workflow relays on Exceptions and can result in unpredictable behaviour in future.
One alternative would be to overload such functions and be more specific with the given types.
When you are sure that this type should not yet be used but will be supported in foreseeable time, you could throw a NotSupportedException with an understandable Errormessage.

Comment: I find it very difficult to judge a design without more information, there are many cases where something would work in one implementation and not in another.  However, you are right in saying that an exception should not be part of the normal flow but I don't think this is the case in this instance...It is more of a indication to the programmer than to control the flow IMHO, obviously, if it is not supported, stop doing it. :)

Comment: @JoelGauvreau Tim is right, this goes against the LSP SOLID principle. If an implementation of an abstraction is not supported it probably means your abstraction is wrong or you are missing a level of abstraction. If it quacks like a duck, swims like a duck, but has wheels its not a duck.

Comment: I disagree. A good example is doing a seek on a stream. Makes sens on a file, can't do it reading a network stream.

Comment: @DavidThielen: but op wanted to throw an exception because the type itself is not supported not because you use a method that is not supported with the current type.